# What's the difference in Python between deleting an object and letting it go out of scope?

Tags: python, cpython

I'm working on a multithreaded Python extension in C that deals a fair bit with the GIL.

There's a problem at exit where code like this shuts down cleanly:

```py
from myextension import ExtensionObject

obj = ExtensionObject()
obj.start()
time.sleep(5)
del obj
# Interpreter exits here
```

But, if I remove the `del obj` from the end and let `obj` go out of scope and get deleted automatically, I get a deadlock while trying to acquire the GIL to do some cleanup in one of the spawned threads.

Is there a fundamental difference between deleting an object and just letting it go out of scope, specifically when it's at the end of program execution?

Edit: Note also that `obj = None` does the same thing as `del obj` in this scenario.

Comment: Is `obj` a module-level ("global") variable in your actual code? Those never "go out of scope" afaik.

Comment: When you explicitly delete the object, its `.__del__()` runs in a fully-functional Python environment.  If you allow the end-of-execution cleanup to handle it, some other objects or modules that `.__del__()` relies on may have already been disposed.

Comment: You cannot delete objects in Python, `del x` doesn't delete an object, it removes the name `x` from the current namespace

Comment: @jasonharper `del x` does *not directly* result in `x.__del__` being called, only incidentally because `x` might have been the last reference to that object. Just to be clear. But yes, `__del__` might not be called if the object is alive at the pii t of interpreter shutdown

Comment: That Python code above is the entire application; everything else is C-extension code.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `def main():` and an `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`, so that the variable is local instead of global. If that makes a difference, then the answer is that it's because global variables have different lifetimes to local variables. If it doesn't make a difference, then something fishy is going on.

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - including C code for *an* extension that will cause the problem you observe, even if it's greatly simplified from the one you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fundamental difference because it is always the garbage collection which does the deleting.

1. You can never delete an object. `del obj` actually deletes the variable and not the object it refers to.
2. Going out of scope is the only way for an object to get deleted.

Both of the above can be defeated by having the variable be referred to by something else:

```py
obj = ExtensionObject()
other = obj  # now there are two labels for your instance.
del obj   # now we have lost obj, but 'other' keeps the instance alive.
```

Comment: Right, that's why this whole thing is confusing to me. If the code I posted above is the entire application, why would a `del obj` just before the program exits be any different from just letting it exit?